# MS Access: Display single record of client w/ most recent contacts listed

Tags: sql, ms-access, grouping

I have a list of clients and their orders over time, while I am sure this is a relatively easy query I'm blanking at the moment. Boss' fault, he's already infected me w/ the wannagohomealready bug.

The screenshot shows a list of records when grouping by Client, but it's grouping by the Agent and the Client whereas I am trying to group by the Client and identify the most recent agent (when multiple agents have serviced a client).

#### Query Design View

[image: Query Design View]

#### Query results

[image: Query results]

I tried the following code but got an 'aggregate in where clause not allowed' error.

```
SELECT tbl_RW_AgentBilling.Customer, tbl_RW_AgentBilling.Agent 
FROM tbl_RW_AgentBilling 
Where tbl_RW_AgentBilling.[OrderDate]=max(tbl_RW_AgentBilling.[OrderDate])
GROUP BY tbl_RW_AgentBilling.Customer, tbl_RW_AgentBilling.Agent;
```

Comment: I've removed unnecessary text. We don't like images with data here, you are better off posting it as the text (code formatted). This is partly because it's easier to read and also will stay here for as long as this site exists. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use correlated subquery to filter out any rows that aren't last according to maximum orderdate for each customer:

```
SELECT t.customer, t.agent as last_agent
FROM tbl_rw_agentbilling t
WHERE t.orderdate = (SELECT max(orderdate)
                     FROM tbl_rw_agentbilling t2
                     WHERE t.customer = t2.customer)
ORDER BY t.customer
```

Comment: `row_number() over (partition` doesn't exist in MS-Access.

Comment: @Andre Well that would explain the error I was getting that I wasn't able to figure out looking up the error text.

I matched Kamil's edited code on my end and it appeared to work, when I attempted to order it by customer either in the code or from the results, it trips out my Access locking it up. Not sure what this is about.

Comment: Simple ORDER BY isn't sufficient? I've included it. This shouldn't be an issue - if it is, this is for another question. Also, if it works for you feel free to accept this answer to show appreciation for help :-)

Comment: I just clicked the accept buttahn, thank ya kindly for the info/help. And yes, even with the ordering in the code it's locking up access to where I have to force close it.